Cannot make Record-Triggered Flow work as expected
I am trying to implement a workaround that is described in this SE answer and got an issue that I still cannot find out.
Context: I have a Boolean field name "Case Status Change" in the Case object where I would like to update it to true whenever the Status field in a Case record has been changed. And then after a specific time (around 1 min), this "Case Status Change" field will be updated it to false again.
Implement: I created this following Record-Triggered Flow:

Object: Case
Trigger: A record is updated
Conditions:
Status Equals New OR
Status Equals Working OR
Status Equals Escalated OR
Status Equals Closed
Run flow when: Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements
It has 2 paths. Run Immediately path to update "Case Status Change" to true, while the Run after 1 min path to update it to false.
Issue: I tried to change a status of a Case record and it did change to "Case Status Change" to true but then after every minute it will keep switching from true to false then false to true....
I can see that the "Run after 1 min" path triggered the flow, made it in an endless loop. So, I tried to change Configure Start with this condition:
Status Is Changed True
But it doesn't let me activate the flow with the new change due to "A flow with a scheduled path that has a time source based on a date or date/time field can’t contain the Is Changed operator in a condition."
How can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

You could achieve this using two flows:
1 - Before Update
Start:

Object: Case
Trigger when: A record is updated
Entry conditions: Status Is Changed True (or the one you have now if it should not start on every status changes. I used Status is changed = true just for testing purpose)
Optimize the Flow for: Fast Field Updates (this let the flow run before the record is saved to the database)


After the start add just an assignment to set the checkbox "Case Status Change" to true
Please note that in a before create/update flow you don't need a DML to update the triggering record.
2 - After Update
Start:

Object: Case
Trigger when: A record is updated
Entry conditions: Case Status Change Equals True
Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements
Optimize the Flow for: Actions and Related Records (this let the flow run after the record is saved to the database)

This flow will have only the scheduled path that runs after 1 minute and that will set the Case Status Change to false against the triggering record

Since the these flows starts on different conditions, there will be no endless loop

Thank you so much @RubenDG. It works. Can you clarify which action/setting determine the flow is "Before Update" or "After Update"? Is this the part "Optimize the Flow for"? While "Fast Fiend Updates" is Before Update and "Actions and Related Records" is After Update?

@DucLe Exactly, when it's optimized for "Fast Field Updates" it runs before the update (or create), while if it's optimized for "Actions and Related Records" it runs after the update (or create). Indeed the description of "Fast Field Updates" is "Update fields on the record that triggers the flow to run. This high-performance flow runs before the record is saved to the database." while the one of "Actions and Related Records" is "Update any record and perform actions, like send an email. This more flexible flow runs after the record is saved to the database"  (emphasis mine)
